# Make Parsec function fail instead of expecting more input

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using Parsec to parse some expressions (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276265/trying-to-program-interactive-session-of-a-toy-language-how-to-use-state-monad) for more context), and most relevant part of my code is:

```
statement :: Parser Stmt
statement = assignStmt <|> simpleStmt

assignStmt :: Parser Stmt
assignStmt =
    do var  <- identifier
       reservedOp "="
       expr <- expression
       return $ Assign var expr

simpleStmt :: Parser Stmt
simpleStmt =
    do expr <- expression
       return $ Simple expr
```

In action:

> **boobla>** foo = 100 + ~100
>   167
>   **boobla>** foo
>   parser error: (line 1, column 4):
>   unexpected end of input
>   expecting letter or digit or "="

Second expression should have evaluated to `167`, value of `foo`.

I thought that when Parsec would try to extract token `reservedOp "="`, it should have failed because there is no such token in the string, then it was to try second function `simpleStmt` and succeed with it. But it works differently: it expects more input and just throws this exception.

What should I use to make `assignStmt` fail if there is no more characters in the string (or in current line). `foo = 10` should be parsed with `assignStmt` and `foo` should be parsed with `simpleStmt`.

Comment: I think you need to say `try assignStmt <|> simpleStmt`. Look up the documentation for `try`.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, it works. Please post it as an answer with a little description of what's happening. If you don't want to spend your time, just say - I will post it as community wiki :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the `try` function.

By default, the `<|>` operator will try the left parser, and if it fails *without consuming any characters*, it will try the right parser.

However, if — as in your case — the parser fails *after* having consumed some characters, and the right parser is *never tried*. Note that this is often the behavior you want; if you had something like

```
parseForLoop <|> parseWhileLoop
```

then if the input is something like "`for break`", then that's not a valid for-loop, and there's no point trying to parse it as a while-loop, since that will surely fail also.

The `try` combinator changes this behaviour. Specifically, it makes a failed parser appear to have consumed no input. (This has a space penalty; the input could have been thrown away, but `try` makes it hang around.)